# How to redirect to a URL when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to redirect to a link when the button is clicked, but it is not working, please need a working code, please.

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("mycom").location.href = "http://mywebsite.com/home.html"";    
}

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Well, `""` isn't helping. And it should probably be `window.location.href`. All of which you could have solved by debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect change your function to the following:

```
function myFunction() {
   window.location = 'http://mywebsite.com/home.html'
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much bro, you're awesome, let me quickly try it out and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks so much, bro it's working now you're all awesome, God Bless.

Comment: Great, would be awesome if you could accept the answer.